# How to extend my XML table

Tags: xml, excel

I exported an XML table and started adding data following the convention.

It goes

```
SessionID | SessionName | ImageKey | Host | Port  | Proto | PuttySession
```

However when adding data I started pasting data into the columns in normal format, as of which I now have about 600 records that are outside the XML table and are not imported when putting back into the program.

I just want to drag the table down to put all those values inside the table.

This should be easy, but I've looked and I cannot find anything.

As usual, Microsoft like to complicate things more than they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to edit the Host field as Excel had by default assigned text in that area as 'General' I changed it to 'Text' to match the XML table.

I then copied all the data outside the XML table and pasted with 'Values'

After which the XML table was extended.